# Why this for loop is exiting before the end?

Tags: android, for-loop, xamarin

I have this for loop which fill Mymatrix (17,27) from a JSON file. 
The problem is that when I debug it, I find that it gets out the loop every time when i=96 ie j=3 and k=15. (I mention also that len=459)

```
            try
            {
                    JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
                    JSONArray nameArray = myjson.Names();
                    len = nameArray.Length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        name = nameArray.GetString(i);
                        JSONArray json_array = myjson.GetJSONArray(name);
                        j = (int)(Integer.ValueOf(name)) / 27;  
                        k = (int)(Integer.ValueOf(name)) % 27;      
                        myMatrix[j, k] = json_array.GetDouble(a); //a=0                         
                    }
             }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
            }
```

Can you please help and figure out why I am having this problem?

Comment: Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: If `len = 459` and you say that it breaks at `i=96`, it means that there is an exception thrown inside `loop` and you should have some logs. If not wrap the place where it breaks with `try{}catch()` so you understand the case

Comment: I had already done that and no exception is thrown.. edited

Comment: do not wrap the `loop` with `try-catch` wrap the logic inside the loop

Comment: maybe provide the ascii version of the json somewhere can see it .  a gist on github , or some file shared in the cloud .